# Private fields not compiling with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a private field for my class, but for some reason, webpack refuses to compile it, it keeps giving me an error, here's an example

```js
class Example {
  #privateField;

  constructor() {...}
}
```

here's the error this Example produces

```
ERROR in ./src/example.js 2:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (2:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class Example {
>   #privateField;
|
|   constructor() {
 @ ./src/example.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Comment: Whats your webpack config look like?

Comment: @Keith
https://pastebin.com/Gu914xXm

Comment: Not used webpack for a while now, but I'm pretty sure you need the babel loader here, as this is a ES2019 feature..  https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: @Keith thanks a lot, that works well, you can answer with this so I can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack, on it's own is just a Javascript bundler, if you have modern JS features, webpack will not understand this,.

Luckily, babel and webpack work well together, so to get ESNext features, you will want to include the babelLoader..

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/